# jquery regex issue match any string a-zA-Z0-1

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reaon, I cannot use nested div, and I m trying to toggle a tree of divs
Div id contains any string except -

```
<div class="tree">
    <div id="a">id=a click to toggle child</div> 
        <div id="a-1"> == id=a-1</div>
            <div id="a-1-f"> == == id=a-1-f</div>
            <div id="a-1-g"> == == id=a-1-g</div>
        <div id="a-2"> == id=a-2</div>
    <div id="b">id=b</div>
</div>

$('.tree').children().on('click',function(){
    var $id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('on');
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $('[id^='+$id+'-]').hide();
    var str = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
    if ($(this).hasClass('on')) {
        $('[id^='+$id+'-'+ str +']').show();
    }
});
```

what should i do for the str above in js

http://jsfiddle.net/cn856y49/4/

What I'm trying to do is: click on any div above: hide all its children and grandchildren, or show only its children.

Hide is working now. However I'm not sure how to make show working.

E.g.. click on id=a will hide all id=a-1, a-xx-xx etc, click on id=a again will only show its next level kids

Comment: Okay but i am unable to guess the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're removing class `on` first on all nodes, then toggling `on` for the current node. Hence it will always be on. Below is a slightly modified version that should do the trick. The initial state of the divs is not correct, but you can likely take it from here.

```
$('.tree').children().on('click',function(){
    var $id = $(this).attr('id');
    var on = !($(this).hasClass('on'));  // toggle "on"
    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('on');
    $('[id^='+$id+'-]').hide();
    var str = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
    if (on) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $('[id^='+$id+']').show();
    }
});
```